# How to disable hadoop combiner?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, combiners

In wordcount example, the combiner is explicitly set in

job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);

I would like to disable the combiner so that the output of mapper is not processed by the combiner. Is there a way to do that using MR config files (i.e. without modifying and recompiling the wordcount code)?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. When you implement `ToolRunner`, it allows you to pass mapreduce configuration parameters through the `-D` flag... but I've never seen the names of the Mapper/Reducer/Combiner classes being changed.

Comment: Let me try to understand your question....So you want a way so that you can turn on and off combiner through some external mechanism ? As such if you don't set the combiner in first place...you won't have a combiner to deal with...so, if you can calrify your question I can have a better answer for you...

Comment: @javadevg sorry for the confusion. "So you want a way so that you can turn on and off combiner through some external mechanism ? As such if you don't set the combiner in first place...you won't have a combiner to deal with" yes this is my question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is your command line

```
hadoop jar your_hadoop_job.jar your_mr_driver \
command_line_arg1 command_line_arg2 command_line_arg3 \
-libjars all_your_dependency_jars
```

Here following parameters

- command_line_arg1
- command_line_arg2
- command_line_arg3

will be passed on to your main method as arg[0], arg[1] and arg[3] respectively. Assuming arg[0] and arg[1] is used for identifying input and output folder. You can use arg[3] to pass a boolean flag like ('1' or 'true' or 'yes') to understand if you want to use combiner and accordingly set combiner. Example below (default...it won't set combiner class)

```
if ( "YyesTrue1".contains(arg[3])){
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
}
```

Comment: This will require you to modify the **Driver** code **not** map reduce code...but yes a code modification is required with this approach. Since its your code which is overwriting the defaults to introduce the combiner...the check has to be put in there only, as that's the last level of configuration.